# Pagination is not working after refresh() is called. [Paging 3 Library]

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

I'm currently working with paging 3 library. I'm able to populate the list and pagination is working as expected. But when I call *adapter.refresh()* method twice by using pull to refresh, the pagination stops working.

I have gone through the documentation and read many articles but no success yet.

One more thing I'm not able to empty the list when I hit pull to refresh. I tried calling *invalidate()* method of PagingSource but it crashes the app.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k2g9mlktv5gee6/22-05-22-10-26-37.mp4?dl=0

**VideoPagingSource.kt**

```
class VideoPagingSource(
    private val apiInterface: ApiInterface,
    private val schoolId: String,
    private val ordering: String?,
    private val courseId: String?,
    private val moduleId: String?,
    private val searchText: String?
) : PagingSource<Int, Video>() {


    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Video>): Int? = null

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Video> {
        val pageNumber = params.key
        return try {
            val response = apiInterface.getVideos(schoolId, ordering, courseId, moduleId, searchText, pageNumber)
            val pagedResponse = response?.body()
            var nextPageNumber: Int? = null
            if (pagedResponse?.links?.next != null) {
                val uri = Uri.parse(pagedResponse.links.next)
                val nextPageQuery = uri.getQueryParameter("page")
                nextPageNumber = nextPageQuery?.toInt()
            }

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response?.body()?.objects.orEmpty(),
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = nextPageNumber
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }


}
```

**PreClassViewModel.kt**

```
class PreClassViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: PreClassRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val queryParamLiveData = MutableLiveData<QueryParams>()

    val videosLiveData = queryParamLiveData.switchMap {

        repository.getVideos(
            schoolId = it.extraArgs[0],
            ordering = it.extraArgs[1],
            courseId = it.courseId,
            moduleId = it.chapterId,
            searchText = it.searchText
        ).cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    }


    fun setQueryParam(queryParams: QueryParams){
        queryParamLiveData.value = queryParams
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem where the adapter provided only the first page after `refresh()`. The reason was a wrong `pageSize` provided to the `PagingConfig`.

Comment: This is hardly an answer, please elaborate with some code & details